# jQuery click function called from div tag

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery function that is called from a couple menus. I want to call it when I click a div tag with the ID="links" but it is not working. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
     $(function () {
         $('#nav a, .recentposts a, #HeaderSpan a, #links').click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var PostName = $(this).attr("href");
             if (PostName == null) {
                 var PostName = $(this).attr("title");  
             }
             PopulatePage(PostName);
             if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
                 history.pushState('', 'New URL: ' + PostName, PostName);
                 e.preventDefault();
             }
             return false;
         });

     });
<div id="links" title="this-is-my-page-name">Continued in Part 2</div>
```

Comment: Is it working for any of the other selectors you have defined in the click event? Or just `#links`?

Comment: As you have it, and making some assumptions about your markup, it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/7CTVX/2/

Comment: Following up on previous comments, try simplifying it.  See if it works in the context of the rest of your code/markup when you only select `#links` and narrow down the contents of the function to a simple `alert` or `console.log`.